# While trying to delete from linked list, I lose the whole list instead of just one int

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is all of my code, I'm not sure if you'll need all of it. I am trying to delete a specific number from the list, and printing what is remaining. However with this code I get the following output:

```
Enter your integer: 5
Enter your integer: 7
Enter your integer: 3
Enter your integer: 0
List is: 
3 -> 7 -> 5 -> 
What do you want to delete? 7
3 -> 
What do you want to delete? 0
Bye.
```

I am just confused on how to point from start to the next integer. TIA.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct intList {
    int number;
    struct intList *next;
} INT_LIST;

int main() {
    INT_LIST *start = NULL, *temp;
    /* Insert into list */
     while(1) {
        int userInput;
        printf("Enter your integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        if(userInput == 0) {
            break;
        }

        INT_LIST *temp = malloc(sizeof(INT_LIST));
        temp->number = userInput;
        temp->next = start;

        start = temp;
    }
    
    /* Print list */
    printf("List is: \n");
    INT_LIST *trvPtr = start;
    while (trvPtr != NULL) {
        if (trvPtr == NULL) {
            printf("%d", trvPtr->number);
        } else {
            printf("%d -> ", trvPtr->number);
            trvPtr = trvPtr->next;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    /* Search and delete value */
    int valueToBeDeleted;
    while (1) {
        printf("What do you want to delete? ");
        scanf("%d", &valueToBeDeleted);
        if (valueToBeDeleted == 0) {
            printf("Bye.");
            break;
        }
        if (start == NULL) {
            printf("Can’t delete from an empty list.");
        } else if (start->number == valueToBeDeleted) { 
            start = start->next;
        } else {
            trvPtr = start;
            while ( (trvPtr->next != NULL) && (trvPtr->next->number != valueToBeDeleted) ) {
                trvPtr = trvPtr->next;
            }
            if (trvPtr->next == NULL) {
                printf("Can’t find %d in the list \n", valueToBeDeleted); 
            } else {
                trvPtr->next = (trvPtr->next)->next;
                printf("%d -> \n", trvPtr->number);
        }
    }
   }

    return 0;
}




   
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct intList {
        int number;
        struct intList *next;
    } INT_LIST;
    
    int main() {
        INT_LIST *start = NULL, *temp;
        /* Insert into list */
         while(1) {
            int userInput;
            printf("Enter your integer: ");
            scanf("%d", &userInput);
            if(userInput == 0) {
                break;
            }
    
            INT_LIST *temp = malloc(sizeof(INT_LIST));
            temp->number = userInput;
            temp->next = start;
    
            start = temp;
        }
        
        /* Print list */
        printf("List is: \n");
        INT_LIST *trvPtr = start;
        while (trvPtr != NULL) {
            if (trvPtr == NULL) {
                printf("%d", trvPtr->number);
            } else {
                printf("%d -> ", trvPtr->number);
                trvPtr = trvPtr->next;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        
        /* Search and delete value */
        int valueToBeDeleted;
        while (1) {
            printf("What do you want to delete? ");
            scanf("%d", &valueToBeDeleted);
            if (valueToBeDeleted == 0) {
                printf("Bye.");
                break;
            }
            if (start == NULL) {
                printf("Can’t delete from an empty list.");
            } else if (start->number == valueToBeDeleted) { 
                start = start->next;
            } else {
                trvPtr = start;
                while ( (trvPtr->next != NULL) && (trvPtr->next->number != valueToBeDeleted) ) {
                    trvPtr = trvPtr->next;
                }
                if (trvPtr->next == NULL) {
                    printf("Can’t find %d in the list \n", valueToBeDeleted); 
                } else {
                    trvPtr->next = (trvPtr->next)->next;
                    printf("%d -> \n", trvPtr->number);
            }
        }
       }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: When you `start = start->next;`, you lose the original `start` pointer creating a memory leak because it cannot be freed. Use `INT_LIST *victim = start; start = start->next; free (victim);`. The remaining logic is a bit convoluted and I'm still looking at it.

Comment: you shouldn't read like that with scanf, use fgets() and then sscanf() instead. you dont check if scanf fails so there may be an extra loop for each \n it finds in the buffer. Always check return values when there is one

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `start = start->next;` creating a memory leak, noted above in the comments, your delete logic is horribly convoluted. If you use both the address of the node pointer along with the node pointer -- there is no need to handle special cases such as the first-node and there is no need to track a previous node. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

A delete routine just iterates with both the pointer address and pointer to node. When the node to remove is found, you simply replace the current node at that address with the next node in the list. You retain a pointer to the current node that you use to free the node memory.

In your case, that simplifies your delete routine to:

```
    INT_LIST **pp = &start
    INT_LIST *p = start;
    
    for (; p; pp = &pp->next, p = p->next)
        if (p->number == valueToBeDeleted) {
            *pp = p->next;
            free (p);
            break;
        }
```

Where `pp` holds the address of the pointer (e.g. *pointer-to-pointer*) and `p` is simply the node pointer. When `p->number == valueToBeDeleted`, the pointer at the address for the current node is replaced with `p->next`. `p` still points to the current node so it is used to `free(p)` -- the node that was at that address before being replace with `p->next`.

Read the article for further understanding on the method and let me know if you have further questions.